# "Multiply"/merge/join string (chr) vectors in R

Tags: r

Total beginner here. I fail at the most basic tasks.

Two vectors of class `chr` and different lengths

```
a <- c("3","5","7","X")
b <- c("A","B","C","D","E")
```

I need to merge them to get a new vector of length $a \times b = 20$ (in this case) of the form

```
> c
[1] "3A" "3B" "3C" "3D" "3E" "5A" "5B" ...
```

so, essentially, I try to merge each string value of `a` to each string value of `b` for every element of `a` and `b`. I have used different search terms to google how to do it, but the results were not as expected. That has to do with the fact that I don't know which term I am looking for, thus the strange title. The "similar questions" to my right (at the time of writing) aren't helping, either, I'm afraid.

The following is almost what I need, but instead of a `data.frame`, I need a vector with the two colums `x` and `y` merged to one column, i.e. a vector of `20 Obs. of 1 variable`. I need glue!

```
> c <- merge(a,b)
> c
   x y
1  3 A
2  5 A
3  7 A
4  X A
5  3 B
6  5 B
7  7 B
8  X B
9  3 C
10 5 C
11 7 C
12 X C
13 3 D
14 5 D
15 7 D
16 X D
17 3 E
18 5 E
19 7 E
20 X E
> class(c)
[1] "data.frame"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to implement an outer product for chars:

`c(outer(a,b,FUN=paste,sep=""))`

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: oh, so "multiply/merge/join", what I was looking for is actually `paste`

Answer (score 1):

I very much like fabiob's answer. Another option that seems a little faster is using `rep` and `paste0`:

```
paste0(rep(a, length(b)), rep(b, each = length(a)))
```

Timing on my computer:

```
> library(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(
    c(outer(a,b,FUN=paste,sep="")),
    paste0(rep(a, length(b)), rep(b, each = length(a)))
)
Unit: microseconds
                                                    expr   min    lq     mean median    uq    max neval
                   c(outer(a, b, FUN = paste, sep = "")) 8.021 8.342 11.33799  8.662 9.304 28.231   100
     paste0(rep(a, length(b)), rep(b, each = length(a))) 4.171 4.492  6.63817  4.813 4.973 45.554   100
```